# Jquery colorbox breaks on page that uses another jquery function in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, colorbox

Hi I have a colorbox which opens on every page when the user clicks a button at the top of the masterpage. I have an FAQs page that I have just discovered breaks the colorbox in Internet Explorer.

This script appears before a repeater that shows the faqs. basically it hides the answers to questions until the user clicks on the question.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function(){
        $(".faqQuestion div").hide();
        $('.faqQuestion').css("background", "url(/Images/top-of-faq-box.jpg)");
        $(".faqQuestion").click(function () {
        $(this).find("div.answer").toggle("fast");

        $(this).find('div.faqQuestion').css("background", "url(/Images/faq-bottom-dd.jpg)");

        });

    });
</script>
```

This script works fine but in IE7 it stops the colorbox from working on this page. Any ideas?

Comment: Put four spaces in front of all your code lines so it gets indented properly.

Comment: @Ollie Edwards - I have edited the post to correctly format the code.

Comment: can you tell us what error you are getting when you see the "errors on page" message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the script into the head of my matsterpage underneath the colorbox document ready script and i now works but with 'errors on page' showing in footer in ie.